# Equation for pure wage contracts in the land market

Tags: development-economics, development, contract-theory, land, contracts

I am reading ["Development Economics"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0691017069) by Debraj Ray. I need to understand the different kinds of contracts in the land market.

Chapter 12.3.1 explains the contract forms. The general equation is:
$ R = \alpha Y + F $

Where $R$ is the total rental that the tenant pays to the landlord.

The tenant can give to the landlord a share of the output. $Y$ denotes agricultural output on the rented land, $\alpha$ is the share of the output that the tenant gives to the landlord. And/or the tenant can give a fixed rent, $F$ to the landlord.

If $\alpha=0$ and $F>0$, this is a fixed-rent contract with rent $F$. The tenant keeps all the output, but pays a rent. I understand that.

If $0 < \alpha < 1$ and $F=0$, then this is a sharecropping contract. The tenant doesn't pay any rent, but gives a fraction of the output to the landlord. I understand that.

If $\alpha=0$ and $F<0$, this can be interpreted as a "pure wage contract" where the wage is
simply $w = − F$: the tenant is not a tenant at all, but a laborer on the landlord’s land.

I don't understand that. The tenant keeps all the output, and in addition he receives a salary from the landlord? Shouldn't it be $\alpha=1$, so that the tenant gives all the output to the landlord and receives a salary, instead of $\alpha=0$?

The same thing is replicated in slide 9 [here](https://www.uio.no/studier/emner/sv/oekonomi/ECON4915/v11/undervisningsmateriale/Lecture2.pdf).

What am I missing?